# How to remap uid/gid in tar archive?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, console, tar

I have the folder with files:

```
 UID     GID 
10000   10000   ./file1.txt
10000   10000   ./file2.txt
10400   10400   ./file3.txt
10402   10402   ./file4.txt
10052   10052   ./file5.txt
```

I want to create tar.bz2 archive with next UID/GID:

```
UID     GID 
0   0    ./file1.txt
0   0    ./file2.txt
400 400  ./file3.txt
402 402  ./file4.txt
52  52   ./file5.txt
```

I want to subtract 10000 from all uid and gid and save result as tar.bz2.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following Python script reads a tarball on standard input and subtracts 10000 from the uid and gid of all its members:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tarfile
import sys

with tarfile.open(fileobj=sys.stdin.buffer, mode="r|*") as in_tar, \
    tarfile.open(fileobj=sys.stdout.buffer, mode="w|", format=tarfile.PAX_FORMAT) as out_tar:
    for member in in_tar:
        member.uid = member.uid-10000
        member.gid = member.gid-10000
        if member.isfile():
            with in_tar.extractfile(member) as file:
                out_tar.addfile(member, file)
        else:
            out_tar.addfile(member)
```

**EDIT**: an earlier version of this post omitted the `format=tarfile.PAX_FORMAT` argument to `tarfile.open()`. This meant that the output tarball would not contain extended attributes that might've been contained in the PAX headers of the input tarball for Python version 3.7 and earlier. Starting with Python 3.8, `PAX_FORMAT` is the default.

The remainder of this post is left for historical purposes.

The problem with this Python script is, that the tarball module does not support extended attributes (xattr, SCHILY) and thus it is not suitable to convert tarballs of root file systems which is the prime reason for wanting to shift uid/gid numbers. Here is a go script that worked:

```golang
package main    

import (
        "archive/tar"
        "io"
        "log"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        tr := tar.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        tw := tar.NewWriter(os.Stdout)

        for {
                hdr, err := tr.Next()
                if err == io.EOF {
                        break
                } else if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                }

                hdr.Uid -= 10000
                hdr.Gid -= 10000
                if err := tw.WriteHeader(hdr); err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                }

                if hdr.Typeflag == tar.TypeReg {
                        if _, err := io.Copy(tw, tr); err != nil {
                                log.Fatal(err)
                        }
                }
        }

        if err := tw.Close(); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
```

Run it with `go run script.go` or compile it with `go build script.go`.